# PHP Array Checking Not Working

Tags: php, html, button

I have an array of booleans, and I want to check them if they're all `TRUE` to generate a button, if not then nothing. However, I always see the button and when I press on it, it doesn't do anything, even when it is supposed to do something.

Please find the code below:

The following code is where I have the array, its `index.php`

```
<?php

session_start();

session_unset();
session_destroy();

$_SESSION["contestant_name"]["topics_done"] = array( FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE ); // topics done
$_SESSION["contestant_name"]["topics_score_correct"] = array();
$_SESSION["contestant_name"]["topics_score_wrong"] = array();
$_SESSION["contestant_name"]["correct"] = 0;
$_SESSION["contestant_name"]["wrong"] = 0;

?>
```

And the next code is from `choosetopic.php`

```
<?php
}

print_r($_SESSION["contestant_name"]["topics_done"]);

if (checkIfAllTrue($_SESSION["contestant_name"]["topics_done"])) {
?>
        <button onclick="complete.php">finish</button>
<?php
}

function checkIfAllTrue ($arr) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        if (!$arr[$i])
            return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I always see the button. What is making this happen? It is supposed to see if the array is all `TRUE`s then it should add the button and when pressed, goes to `complete.php`, however, I always see the button, and even after finishing all the topics, and I press it, nothing happens.

Thanks

Comment: Why did you destroy your session in first code block? You cant access session variables in bits after that

Comment: Why post all of this code? Minimise it to the code that matters. Most of this is irrelevant. You're only asking about checking booleans and generating a button, no need for all the list generation malarkey and whatnot.

Comment: I'd rather see too much code rather than the far too little code that I usually get treated to in questions.

Comment: @Foo_Chow Without using it, I always had the same name entered, and scores, so I tried `session_destroy()` and it worked.

Comment: @WolfmanJoe That's a different problem.

Comment: @aizen92 just use `unset($_SESSION['variableToUnset']);` to get rid of one variable instead of destroying your entire session

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

I just ran this piece of code below online, 
at http://writecodeonline.com/php/
and its working.....copy it and test it yourself there...
So your issue is probably related to sessions instead.
What do you get when you var_dump that $_SESSION variable youre testing??

ARE YOU SURE YOU RAN **session_start()** at the top of the choosepage.php file?
You run it at the start of the index.php file, but check the choosepage.php file

If thats not the issue, then my guess is that you're resetting the variable everytime you're handling it, and not actually changing the correct keys......hence the NULL value the first time round

```
  function checkTrue ($arr) {
  for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    if (!$arr[$i])
        return FALSE;
   }

   return TRUE;
   }

  $array = array(false,true,true,true); //This is your $_SESSION variable simulated

 if (checkTrue($array)) {?>
    <button onclick="complete.php">finish</button>
 <?php };?>
```

Comment: I tried `if ($arr[$i]=="FALSE")` but did not work.
Why do I have syntax here?

Comment: What is printed when you var_dump($_SESSION['contestant_name']['topics_don'])?

Comment: I ran your original code against an array of booleans, and its working fine, so is it the fact that your button is always showing that makes you suspect its not working?

Comment: @KyleK first time I get `NULL`, then after finishing one topic, I get `array(1) { [0]=> bool(true) }`

Comment: Well then logically, wouldn't the button always be there????  Since it will always be true?

Comment: Yes, so the array of booleans isn't initialised, right? But the thing is I saved it in a session why am I not getting it?

Comment: Silly question, but did you run session_start() at the top of the choosetopic.php?

Comment: Oh, you made it seem like they were different pages, one named index.php and one named choosepage.php

Comment: If theyre different pages, you have to call session_start() on each page

Comment: they are two pages. The first `index.php` is where I declared and initialised the array of boolean into `$_SESSION["contestant_name"]["topics_done"]` I also have `session_start()` in `index.php` and in the next page `choosetopic.php` the first line of code is `session_start()` and later in the `choosetopic.php` page I am using the function to check the array

Comment: Ok just making sure.....well then something else is going on, you're gonna have to post more code, on where that variable gets handled....so as to try find errors there

Comment: If you just var_dump() it at the very top of the choosetopic.php page....before any logic, what do you get????  It should be your initialized array

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31543/discussion-between-kylek-and-aizen92)